# Construct enum from rawValue without rawValue

Tags: swift

I would like to get the enum from a raw value (String) but I am unable to do that with rawValue since I am using associated value. I have added the current implementation at the bottom.

As I am unable to use rawValue with associated value, this is my updated enum.

```
enum Enum {
    case Case1
    case Case2
    case Case3(value: String)
}

// Will not work
Enum(rawValue: stringValue)
```

I used to get the enum based on a string using this code `Enum(rawValue: stringValue)` but it doesn't work since it does not have a rawValue.

My current idea is to create a function where it would read the string and returns the enum. Would that be the best option or there is a cleaner way where I could do this?

```
func getEnum(value: String) -> Enum {
        switch value {
        case "value1":
            return .Case1
        case "value2":
            return .Case2
        default:
            return .Case2
        }
    }
```

This is the current implementation I have. But I would like to update my enum by having an associated value.

```
enum Enum: String {
    case Case1 = "value1"
    case Case2 = "value2"

}
Enum(rawValue: "value1") -> Returns Case1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do - so `value1` would give `Case1`, what about `Case2`? And most importantly, what string would give `Case3`, and what would the associated value be?

Comment: Sorry I didn't fill complete the code. Yes, "value2" will return Case2.

Comment: Just create your own initializer `init(rawValue: String)` and put whatever logic you want in it in there. You can assign self like this in an `enum` init `self = .Case1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Swift enumeration can have either raw values *or* associated values, but not both:

> If a value (known as a raw value) is provided for each enumeration case, the value can be a string, a character, or a value of any integer or floating-point type.
> Alternatively, enumeration cases can specify associated values of any type to be stored along with each different case value, much as unions or variants do in other languages.

Depending on your use case, you have a few options. But the closest I can think of, is splitting your enum into 2 enums: first contains raw string values, the other associated types:

```
enum StandardValue: String {
    case string1
    case string2
    // ...
}

enum Enum {

    case standard(value: StandardValue)
    case custom(value: String)

    static func getValue(string: String) -> Enum {

        guard let standardValue = StandardValue(rawValue: string) else {
            return .custom(value: string)
        }

        return .standard(value: standardValue)
    }
}
```

You still need a function to create `Enum`, but this way you don't need a switch for every case, you just need to handle 2 cases (standard and custom).

Comment: A custom initializer makes more sense than `getValue(string: String)`

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Sure, you can add a custom initializer to the second enum, instead of `getValue`. Not the point of the answer though. My point was to use 2 enums, instead of 1. But having a custom initializer on one enum will still require you to have a switch statement for each and every case. So it's not solving the awkwardness of the original solution, which he already has